# Wrong image url output with advanced custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have two different Advanced custom fields in the same page, one is working fine, however the other when comes out weird, even though I am using the same bit of code (not the same Field Name obviously ^^)

The custom field loads:

```
<img src="383, , _MG_9152, , UT, http://media5.utt.se/2013/06/MG_9152webb-e1370957481647.jpg, 680, 291, Array">
```

and not as it should be:

```
<img src="http://media5.utt.se/2013/06/MG_9152webb-e1370957481647.jpg"&gt;
```

My code:

```
<?php global $post;
  $id = '4'; //set the post id here
  $post = get_post($id); //get the post
  setup_postdata($post); //setup the post
?>
<div class="splash">
    <img src="<?php the_field('splash'); ?>"/>
</div>
```

Any clue where the problem lies?

Comment: can you post the code you use to save|update that custom field please?

Comment: @iEmanuele if I am not mistaken this is handled by the plugin www.advancedcustomfields.com

Comment: @Carl Papworth what type of field are you using? text or image?

Comment: @BojanaŠekeljić I had this figured out, but how is it possible that the plugin save the value of that custom fields in that manner? You have probably occurred in the process of saving the custom field

Comment: @carl papworth my guess is that you are using the wrong field type, it seems that it is pulling the whole object not just the url, and when you place it as url in img tag this is what happens, but i am just guessing here as i don't know what type of fields are you using

Comment: Got answer at ACF-forum and just as you set it was a settings issue. me=n00b :D